# The short story about self-aware appliances that link together and cause mayhem?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

This is a story about the 'Internet of Things gone wrong'.

If I recall correctly, the protagonist's girlfriend decides she'd rather be with a ball of appliances than the dude, who has tried and failed to keep the things from linking up... if I'm right that's how the story ends.

*Maybe Cory Doctorow?*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is "[...And The Dish Ran Away With The Spoon](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?308991)" by Paul Di Filippo, originally published in 2003.

> *The information was embedded in an Aeron chair mated with several
> other objects: a Cuisinart, an autonomous vacuum cleaner with numerous
> interchangeable attachments, an iPod, and a diagnostic and therapeutic
> home medical tool known as a LifeQuilt. As rivals go, this spontaneous
> assemblage—or "bleb," as most people called such random accretions of
> intelligent appliances and artifacts, after the biological term for an
> extrusion of anomalous cells—wasn't particularly handsome. Rather
> clunky looking, in fact. But apparently, it had been devoted to Cody
> from the day it was born, and I guess women appreciate such attention.
> I have to confess that I had been ignoring Cody shamefully during the
> period when the Aeron bleb must've been forming and beginning to court
> her, and so I have no one to blame for the threat of losing her but
> myself. Still, it hurt. I mean, could I really come in second to a
> bleb? That would truly reek.*

You can read the full story online [here](https://www.lexal.net/scifi/scifiction/originals/originals_archive/difilippo3/difilippo31.html)

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Have you read this before?

Comment: Yes, it's been *repeatedly collected*. It was in the Yrs best scifi (23) and Mammoth Book of Extreme Scifi.

Comment: YES! Thank you Valorum. @adamant too, thank you, I appreciate you setting me straight on how we do things here.

Comment: @RobertLeachman - Glad you're happy. Don't forget to upvote and press the "accepted" button to show that you've accepted that this is the correct answer.